# Git repository not found, push changes username

Tags: git, github, git-push

I get the following when I try to push:

> Pushing to `https://github.com/jsrava/matecheck.git` remote: Repository not found.

The 'b' is missing in the username above, it should be jsbrava. I've typed it several times and it always removes the 'b'.

Comment: Typed it in what OS, platform? Is it just that repo?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your remote is `origin`

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/jsbrava/matecheck.git
```

will set the correct url.